# How to change the Redux state based on an Electron menu click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, electron

I'm building an [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) application based on React and Redux. I'm starting with the [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate), which is pretty minimalistic and easy to understand.

*I want the user to open a file on the Electron menu, and as a result, I want to call a reducer and change the Redux application state. Pretty simple concept.*

The problem is that I don't know how to change the Redux state from outside my root component. The Electron menu is defined in the [main.js file](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate/blob/master/main.js). The root component is defined in the [index.js file](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/index.js), together with the `Redux state` (the `store` variable).

In the `main.js` file, I want to do something like this:

```
  submenu: [{
    label: '&Open',
    accelerator: 'Ctrl+O',
    click: function() {
        // I want to change my app Redux state here. But I don't know how.
    }
  }
```

Any idea?

Comment: To change the app state, simply call an action. Is it not possible in current context?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You could obtain the filename in the main process and then send it to the renderer process via Electron IPC, for example:

In `main.js`

```
// mainWindow = new BrowserWindow();

submenu: [{
  label: '&Open',
  accelerator: 'Ctrl+O',
  click: () => {
    // popup a dialog to let the user select a file
    // ...
    // then send the filename to the renderer process
    mainWindow.webContents.send('open-file', selectedFilename);
  }
}]
```

In `index.js`

```
import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron';

ipcRenderer.on('open-file', (event, filename) => {
  store.dispatch({ type: 'OPEN_FILE', filename });
});
```

Comment: God bless your soul.

Comment: Very nice solution

Answer (score 4):

The other option is to build your menu on the renderer side (in `index.js`) using the `remote` module, then you could call the dispatcher directly from the click callback.